# Longest Run on a Snowboard - stack overflow

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack-overflow, backtracking

I have been practicing backtracking for my exam in Algo and data structure.
Our prof gave us the problem "Longest Run on a Snowboard" which basically asks to find the longest route in a given matrix going up, right, down, left by checking if the current position is bigger than the next.

So my take was to check if my current position is bigger than the next and keep track of the movements with variables dx, sx, down, up and call recursively the function updating the i and j pointers of the matrix.
The variable count counts the number of steps we are able to complete in a given path which is then stored in an ArrayList.
But now I'm getting a stack overflow because the code cant exit the recursion but I dont know where I missed something.
I checked the bounds of i and j and it should exit when we get at the end but it just loops.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Snowboard {

    public static int testCase;         // INPUT TESTCASES
    public String nameRoute;            // INPUT NAME OF THE TRACK
    public static int N;                // N DIMENSION MATRIX
    public static int M;                // M DIMENSION MATRIX
    public int[][] route;               // MATRIX

    public List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();          // KEEPS TRACK OF THE LONGEST COUNT OF THE TRACK



        public void readFile(){
            int max = 0;
            try {
                File myObj = new File ("D:\\Intellij\\EsercitazioneProva\\snowboardFile");
                Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
                while ( myReader.hasNextLine() ){
                    testCase = myReader.nextInt();
                    for (int k = 0; k < testCase; k++){
                        int count = 0;
                        nameRoute = myReader.next();
                        N = myReader.nextInt();
                        M = myReader.nextInt();
                        route = new int[N][M];
                        System.out.println(testCase + " " + nameRoute + " " + N + " " + M);
                        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                            for (int j=0;j<M;j++){
                                route[i][j] = myReader.nextInt();
                                System.out.print(route[i][j] + " ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                        }

                        longesRoute(0, 0, route, count);
                        System.out.println(nameRoute + ":" + " " + checkMax(list)); // OUTPUT OF THE LONGEST ROUTE IN GIVEN TRACK

                    }


                }


            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("Error File not Found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Snowboard d = new Snowboard();
            d.readFile();
    }


    public int checkMax(List<Integer> list){
            int max = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                if ( max < list.get(i)){
                    max = list.get(i);
                }
            }
            return max;
    }


    public void longesRoute(int i, int j, int[][] route, int count){

            int dx = 0;
            int sx = 0;
            int up = 0;                 // COORDINATES THAT KEEP TRACK IF I CAN GO IN A DIRECTION
            int down = 0;


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(i + " " + j + " ");

    if( j < M-1 ){                      // CHECK IF WE ARE IN BOUNDS
        if( (route[i][j] > route[i][j+1]) && ( dx != 1 )){   // GOING RIGHT
            count++;
            dx = 1;
            longesRoute(i, j+1, route, count);
        }
        else{
            dx = 1;
        }
    }
    else dx = 1;

    if ( i < N-1 ){                     // CHECK IF WE ARE IN BOUNDS
        if( (route[i][j] > route[i+1][j]) && ( down != 1)  ){    // GOING DOWN
            count++;
            down = 1;
            longesRoute(i+1, j, route, count);
        }
        else{
            down = 1;
        }
    }
    else down = 1;

    if ( j > 0 ){                       // CHECK IF WE ARE IN BOUNDS
        if( (route[i][j] > route[i][j-1]) && ( sx != 1) ){      // GOING LEFT
            count++;
            sx = 1;
            longesRoute(i, j-1, route, count);
        }
        else{
            sx = 1;
        }
    }
    else sx = 1;

    if( i > 0 ){                        // CHECK IF WE ARE IN BOUNDS
        if( (route[i][j] > route[i-1][j]) && ( up != 1) ){      // GOING UP
            count++;
            up = 1;
            longesRoute(i-1, j, route, count);
        }
        else{
            up = 1;
        }
    }
    else up = 1;



            if ( (up == 1) && (down == 1) && (dx == 1) && (sx == 1) ){  // IF TRUE THEN WE CANT GO ANYWHERE SO CHANGE POSITION IN MATRIX
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("CHANGE IT UP");
                list.add(count);
                count = 0;

                if( j < M-1)  {             // CHECKING IF WE ARE IN J BOUNDS
                    longesRoute(i, j+1, route, count);
                }
                else if( i < N-1 ){         // CHECKING IF WE ARE IN I BOUNDS
                    longesRoute(i+1, 0, route, count);
                }else return;               // IF FALSE THEN WE ARE AT THE END OF THE MATRIX SO END.


            }

        if( j < M-1)  {
            longesRoute(i, j+1, route, count);
        }
        else if( i < N-1 ){
            longesRoute(i+1, 0, route, count);
        }else return;



    }
```

```
// The data is given from a file example:
1    // TestCases
Spiral 5 5
1 2 3 4 5
16 17 18 19 6
15 24 25 20 7
14 23 22 21 8
13 12 11 10 9
```

Comment: Because you're only allowed to go downhill, you don't benefit from keeping track of `dx`, `sx`, `up`, or `down`.  As to your question, your very last if-else chain is sus.